# Any tools for signal logging Motorola SB6141 on my PC?

Tags: cable-modem

For years I had an application someone had written for older Motorola Surfboards.  You could run the app in your tray and it would poll the cable modem and log all of the signal data in a csv file every X seconds.  It was pretty useful as you can imagine in finding out if you had intermittent problems or odd patterns in single degradation based on temperature or other environmental factors, especially if you let the application run for a few days.

However that app won't work with newer Docsis 3 Surfboards.  Does anyone know of a similar app or tool that I could use to log the same type of data locally on my pc?  Does any logging tool exist for the SB6141 at all?

Comment: Don't most of these Motorola modem's give this information by just opening up the gateway address in a browser? Typically 192.168.1.1, and then that page might have other sub-pages, one of which offers these stats - probably formatted as html.

Comment: No, they give 1 page of data at http://192.168.100.1/cmLogs.htm.  It gives you no signal data on that page.

Comment: At the top level page (just 192.168.100.1) can you view the source and look for other hidden page links?

Answer (score 0):

The older Surfboards (3100-5101s at least) could be polled with SNMP v1, and a community-string of `public`.  I see that on the [manufacturer's data sheet](http://www.arrisi.com/modems/datasheet/SB6141/SB6141_Data_Sheet.pdf) (page 2, Network Management) that SNMP v1 is not there.

While SNMP v3 is a very different paradigm, v2c is essentially the same as v1, as far as authentication and parameter passing goes, but uses 64 bit counters instead of 32-bit counters, and so can deal with numbers > 4 billion.  An SNMP v2(c) query is the same length as a v1 query, but the byte values are slightly different.

Have you checked with the original site of your monitoring utility to see if they've updated their software?  Or, is there a setting to select V2(c) in its settings?

Comment: Thats something I hadn't considered.  NewEgg's specifications page says it supports snmp v2 & v3.  I'll test it and accept your answer if it works.